# NgbDropdown autoClose "outside" is not working

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I am using angular4 with ng-bootstrap. I want to close my dropdown on clicking outside the dropdown (rest of document). After reviewing the documentation i identified that **autoClose Type: boolean | "outside" | "inside"**.
But when i tried to set it as param  config.autoClose =  'outside' then my script start showing this error "Type '"outside"' is not assignable to type 'boolean'."

Any suggestions or help on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *was suspecting* that you are using a version of [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) that doesn't have support for `autoClose="outside"` yet (it was introduced very recently, in `1.0.0-beta.1`, see the changelog: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta1-2017-08-11)

After closer investigation, though, it turned out that we had a small bug in ng-bootstrap for which I've sent a PR already: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/1754. This fix will be merged before the next release.

I believe that as a for now you can use a work-around by casting config like so:

```
(<any>config).autoClose = 'outside';
```

Comment: I am using the latest version of ng-bootstrap (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.1 ).

Comment: @user3373970 - oh, I see - this is an actual bug on our side - check the updated answer for more details and a work-around.

Comment: @pkozlowski-opensource  I tried your suggested casting solution config.autoClose = 'outside' but still getting same error. Can you please let me know when this issue will be fixed and merged with repo.

Comment: @user3373970 the actual casting should be `(<any>config).autoClose = 'outside';`, updated the answer. The actual fix will be part of the next release (expected this week).

Comment: Commenting if this helps anyone now more than 2 years later. Oddly I have the same issue - I'm on ng-bootstrap 2.0.0. What worked was to use single quotes around the config value when using it as an input to the component as so: `[autoClose]="'outside'"`

Answer (score 6):

In **Angular**, if you are using **ng-Bootstrap**. If you want that your dropdown gets closed on click in any part of the screen, then add this line in your code.

```
[autoClose]="true"
```

Your code will look like

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [autoClose]="true">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Option 1 </button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Option 2 </button>
 </div>
```

If you don't want then put.

```
[autoClose]="false"
```

Comment: Also, for this to work, your items in the dropdown should have the `ngbDropdownItem` directive. Won't work without it.