# angular dropdown bootstrap Problem [autoClose]="'outside'" doesn't work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown

angular dropdown bootstrap Problem  [autoClose]="'outside'" doesn't work

i tried also [autoClose]="outside", the same problem always

```
<div ngbDropdown #searchDropdown="ngbDropdown" class="input-group" [autoClose]="'outside'">
```

Comment: try `autoClose="outside"`

Comment: same problem ...

Comment: I hope this is helpfull [ngbdropdown-autoclose-outside-is-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716754/ngbdropdown-autoclose-outside-is-not-working)